# Terminal doesn't work and only shows codes on output(vs code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed python from the extensions, named my file `dohoon.py` but the code doesn't run in terminal. If I write the code in terminal and press enter, the code works out perfectly but if I write my code on my file and press the run code button on the upper right, the code doesn't work in terminal and vs just shows 'output' with bunch of colorful codes that I cannot understand. So, how can I write code in the file, run it with the play button and make it work in terminal?

Comment: "If I write the code on terminal and press enter, the code works out perfectly" Python does not run directly in a terminal shell, do you mean an interactive Python prompt? "Shows 'output' with bunch of colorful codes that I cannot understand." can you add a screenshot or something? That's a pretty vague description.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the second "Run Python File"

[image]

The first one "Run Code" will run the file and tell you the result in "OUTPUT".

The second one "Run Python File" can show the result in your default terminal.

Comment: Of course, you can add this line to your setting.json "code-runner.runInTerminal": true if you want to continue using "Run Code".